# Getting error while put any text in Host Name field in IIS 7.5 while set up website

Tags: iis-7.5

I have created a website and virtual directory in IIS 7.5 and map the root folder to this website.
I put `Host Name` blank and browse the website by typing `http://localhost:82/` in browser.
Website running properly.
Now I put `abc` in `Host Name` text box and browse the website following error display:

```
This page can't be displayed
•Make sure the web address http://abc:82 is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got answer.
Actually I have to make en entery in `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` for `abc` hostname